# Downloading and "using" image from website

Tags: android

So I have an app which loads a website (one with only an image on it) and displays it in a WebView, but I want to make a feature so that the first time the image is loaded, it saves it to internal storage, and when requesting that image again, instead of loading it from the website it will load it from storage (so basically just checking if it is downloaded, and if it is, load from storage instead of web, for use offline etc.)

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use image loader packages for android that do it all such as
[glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)